# Как ускорить проверку оптимальности графа?

Tags: графы

Всем привет. Вот такая задача:
В стране X есть n городов, которым присвоены номера от 1 до n. Столица страны имеет номер n. Между городами проложены железные дороги.

Однако дороги могут быть двух типов по ширине полотна. Любой поезд может ездить только по одному типу полотна. Условно один тип дорог помечают как R, а другой как B. То есть если маршрут от одного города до другого имеет как дороги типа R, так и дороги типа B, то ни один поезд не сможет по этому маршруту проехать. От одного города до другого можно проехать только по маршруту, состоящему исключительно из дорог типа R или только из дорог типа B.

Но это ещё не всё. По дорогам страны X можно двигаться только от города с меньшим номером к городу с большим номером. Это объясняет большой приток жителей в столицу, у которой номер n.

Карта железных дорог называется оптимальной, если не существует пары городов A и B такой, что от A до B можно добраться как по дорогам типа R, так и по дорогам типа B. Иными словами, для любой пары городов верно, что от города с меньшим номером до города с бОльшим номером можно добраться по дорогам только какого-то одного типа или же что маршрут построить вообще нельзя. Выясните, является ли данная вам карта оптимальной.

Ну и дальше задаются вот эти R и B Дороги. В лоб я ее решил, то есть просто тупо нахожу все пути от вершины 1 до N, и смотрю, чтобы там были только одного типа дороги. Но уже  на 25 городах работает все безумно долго. Понимаю, что есть какой-то более простой алгоритм, но ничего в голову не приходит. Дайте какую-нибудь идею, в какую сторону думать?

Comment: Рекомендую: 1) обязательно задавать вопрос так, чтобы не надо было читать весь длинный текст, а то будет мало желающих отвечать. Я отредактирую заголовок сам в данном случае, но учтите на будущее. 2) Лучше (на ваше усмотрение) привести своё решение более детально, кому-то может понадобится для ответа вам.

Comment: А вы завершаете проверку пути досрочно, если обнаруживается косяк, или строите путь целиком и только после этого начинаете проверять его корректность? Мне кажется, если вовремя обрубать построение пути, всё будет не настолько печально. Ну и хотелось бы какие-то исходные данные и код посмотреть, чтобы разговор был предметным.

Comment: А, хотя нет, там же вариант, что пути не существует отдельно нужно проверить. Тут нужно тщательнее...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все рёбра графа `B` переворачиваете и смешиваете с рёбрами графа `R`. В получившемся общем ориентированном графе ищете циклы. Если есть хоть один, карта не оптимальна.

Решение работает за время пропорциональное суммарному числу рёбер в `R` и `B`.

Comment: То есть в одну сторону ребра R, в другую B, все ребра считаем одинаковыми, и просто ищем циклы? Интересно, попробую. Спасибо!

Comment: Все равно TL, не пойму как тут в комментарий добавить код, в справке написано Ctrl+K, не работает.

Comment: В комментарии нельзя добавить код с форматированием.

Comment: Киньте ссылку на описание алгоритма как вы проверяли циклы.

Comment: Вот выше отдельным ответом привел код, как проверяю циклы. Ну и соответственно dfs(x) запускаю по очереди для всех вершин графа пока не найду цикл

Comment: Все заработало. Нашел небольшую ошибку. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Строите ДВА отдельных графа, R и B.
Для каждого обходом в ширину (или любым другим способом) строите таблицу связности, в которой `A[i,j]=0` при `i<j` означает, что путь из `i` в `j` не существует, а `A[i,j]=1` - существует

Делаете AND соответствующих элементов обеих таблиц между собой. Если результат состоит из одних нулей - карта оптимальная.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Действительно все просто

Comment: Да, все работает, но на 5000 элементах все равно за TL выхожу. Видимо нужно что-то еще оптимизировать...

Answer (score 0):

Вот так все заработало. Всем спасибо!

```
static void dfs(int v)
        {
            if (flag == 1) return;
            visited[v] = 1;
    
            for (int i = 0; i < inpArrayGraph[v].size(); i++)
            {
                int to = inpArrayGraph[v].get(i);
                if (visited[to] == 1)
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    return;
                }
                else if (visited[to] == 0) dfs(to);
                if (flag == 1) return;
            }
            visited[v] = 2;
        }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]